# c++ class inheritance and operator overloading; do operator overloads get inherited?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operator-overloading

Just a quick question, if I have a template class:

```
template <typename T>
class foo {
public:
    bool operator!=(foo& other) const {
        //...
    }

}
```

And then I inherit said class:

```
template <typename T>
class bar : public foo<T> {
    //...
}
```

Does the operator overload get inherited? And if not, how would I go about implementing it so that it does... because currently in my test class, this brings up an error:

```
for (bar<int> i(baz); i != bar<int>(); i++) {}
```

The ++ operator is implemented in the bar class, so that works, but the != operator is apparently not inherited. The error message is:

```
error: no match for 'operator!=' in 'i != bar<int>(0u, 0u)'
note: candidate is: bool foo<T>::operator!=(foo<T>&) const [with T = int]
```

That pretty much sums up the problem I'm having, so I'm just wondering how I'd go about inheriting the operator overload.

Comment: Not a full answer to your question, but such operators should be implemented as non-member functions. That would (solve your problem (and behave better in a few other ways as well)

Comment: @jalf: And [it happened again](http://xkcd.com/859/).

Comment: But at least it happened in a new way. it's usually that you forget to close your parenthesis. This time I added a `(` where it makes absolutely no sense whatsoever!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your operator definition isn't quite correct:

```
bool operator!=(foo& other) const {
    //...
}
```

should be

```
bool operator!=(const foo& other) const {
    //...
}
```

since you are trying to compare with a temporary, which can only be bound to a const reference.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared it up! Have programmed too much Java and not enough C++, so I seem to forget const references/declarations a little too often...